# How do we check the Button is enabled for the List of the Task status using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a page where I will be getting multiple status list i.e. Completed , pending and In progress.
For each status I should check whether the Bypass button is enabled or not?

here is my code

```java
Map<String, Long> projectTasks = workflowApi.getProjectTasks(projectDetails.getId());
List<TaskStatus> taskList = Arrays.asList(TaskStatus.PENDING, TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
TaskStatus.COMPLETED, TaskStatus.REJECTED, TaskStatus.SUSPENDED);
taskList.get(0).getStatus();

System.out.println("The status lists are:"+ taskList);
```

I am able to print the Status list but not able to assert the Button display status.